# iOS Swift Get Image Coordinates in UIImage With GestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've got a simple app that displays an image inside a ImageView which is inside a scrollview which in turn is in a stack view along with some buttons.  I've set up the imageview/scrollview to be able to pinch/zoom.

Now, I've added a TapGesture Recognizer to detect touchs and I then grab the x,y coordinates in the image.  Based previous StackOverflow questions/answers, I translate the coordinates in the gesture recognizer back to the original image.  Here is my gesture callback.

```
@IBAction func didTapImage(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    guard let image = imageView.image else {
        return
    }
            
    let touchPoint: CGPoint = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: imageView)
    
    print("image clicked: x: \(touchPoint.x) y: \(touchPoint.y)")
    print("image size is \(image.size)")
    print("frame size is \(imageView.frame.size)")
    
    // touch pont relative to imageView then translate to the image coordinates
    let x_prop = touchPoint.x / imageView.frame.size.width
    let y_prop = touchPoint.y / imageView.frame.size.height
    
    let new_x = x_prop * image.size.width
    let new_y = y_prop * image.size.height
    print("x_prop: \(x_prop), y_prop: \(y_prop)")
    print("new_x: \(new_x) new_y: \(new_y)")
}
```

What I'm seeing is that close to the center of the image, the coordinates seem pretty accurate.  When I go to click at roughly 0,0, I'm finding the X is really distorted and Y seems accurate.

I've set the image, imageview, and scrollview to be scaleAspectFit.

Any ideas why the x,y coordinates in the gesture call back are distorted?
(Below is the code I use to assemble the main view)

Bobby

```
        //scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        // set up image view for scale aspect fit, allow user interaction (for clicking)
        // and add the gesture for detecting touch
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action:#selector(didTapImage))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
        imageView.image = theImage

        // stackview setup
        stackView.frame = view.bounds
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        //stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        //stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.spacing = 5
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(selectButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(resetButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textView)
        
        contentView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        contentView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // set up layout constraints
        // set constraints
        selectButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.1*view.frame.size.height).isActive = true
        resetButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.1*view.frame.size.height).isActive = true
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.40*view.frame.size.height).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.40*view.frame.size.height).isActive = true

        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
'''
Code to draw crosshair on image:

'''
func markImage(x_prop: CGFloat, y_prop: CGFloat)
    {
        guard let image = imageView.image else {
            return
        }
        let imageSize = image.size
        let scale: CGFloat = 0
        let length: CGFloat = max(imageSize.width/48, imageSize.height/48)
        let gap: CGFloat = length / 1.5
        var actualX = imageSize.width * x_prop
        var actualY = imageSize.height * y_prop
        
        //actualX = actualX.rounded()
        //actualY = actualY.rounded()
        
        print("markImage at \(actualX) \(actualY)")
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, scale)
        
        imageView.image!.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
        var uiColor = hexToUIColor(rgbVal: 0xFE00DD)
        uiColor.setFill()

        // horizontal lines in target
        var rectangle = CGRect(x: actualX - length - gap, y: actualY-gap/2,
                               width: length, height: gap)
        UIRectFill(rectangle)
        
        rectangle = CGRect(x: actualX + gap, y: actualY-gap/2,
                           width: length, height: gap)
        UIRectFill(rectangle)
        
        // vertical lines in target
        rectangle = CGRect(x: actualX-gap/2, y: actualY - length - gap,
                           width: gap, height: length)
        UIRectFill(rectangle)
        
        rectangle = CGRect(x: actualX-gap/2, y: actualY + gap,
                           width: gap, height: length)
        UIRectFill(rectangle)
        
        // for testing, draw a white rectangle 20x20 centered at actual x,y
        uiColor = hexToUIColor(rgbVal: 0xFFFFFF)
        uiColor.setFill()
        rectangle = CGRect(x: actualX-10, y: actualY-10, width: 20, height: 20)
        UIRectFill(rectangle)
        
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        imageView.image = newImage
        
    }
'''
```

Comment: A bit confusing... you say *"ImageView which is inside a scrollview which in turn is in a stack view along with some buttons"* ... but then your code shows two buttons, an image view and a text view, all as arranged subviews of a stack view... the stack view is in a "content" view... and the contentView is the subview of the scroll view?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Yes, stack view has stacked, vertically, two buttons, scroll view, and text view.  I omitted some of that code to cut down on the extraneous amounts of code for people to examine.  Here is the hierarchy: view -> scrollview -> contentview -> stackview -> button, button, imageview, textview.  I had to add the contentview so that pinch/zoom would work properly.

Comment: OK - and, do you want the **Point** coordinates of the tap? Or do you want the **Pixel** coordinates?

Comment: I guess I don't know the diff.  My code is taking touch CGPoint and then converting to pixel coordinates in image based on previous StackOverflow answers.  But what I'm finding is the touch point X value is not accurate but the touch point Y value is.  Baffled.  I've been playing with different view frame sizes and such for couple of days.

Comment: If I click in center of image, the touch point coordinates in ImageView of roughly 380,80 for an imageView size of 736,166  If I click on the upper left corner of image, I get something like 226,7 which is pretty accurate Y but X value is not valid.  Its almost as if the image is not being scaled equally.  But I've set scaleAspectFit on image, imageView.

Comment: **Points** vs **Pixels** matters, depending on what you want to do with the touch point... For example - are you trying to get the color of the tapped **pixel**? Are you trying to get the point to place another view (such as a label)? Are you planning on using the touch to **draw** on the image?

Comment: I'm trying to  draw a cross hair at the point of touch.  I thought I was properly converting touch point x,y to image pixel x,y.  Y seems accurate but X is not.  Thanks.

Comment: *"draw a cross hair at the point of touch"* -- do you want to ***display*** a cross hair (use a `CAShapeLayer`, for example)? Do you want to actually ***draw*** it on the *bitmap* and save it to disk? I don't want to sound harsh, but to get help you really need to take the time to define and describe exactly what you're trying to do... otherwise, we spend time giving you an answer, only to find out that it's not really what you want.

Comment: For drawing a crosshair, I take the converted touchPoint x,y and create a graphics image context and draw a rectangle on the image.  I then take newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageConext().  Not saving to disk but just displaying new image with crosshair drawn on it.  I save the old image for reverting back.  Don't mind the questions.  I had not seen CAShapeLayer for display vs draw.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated the original question to include the code that I use to draw the crosshair on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your calculated coordinates are off is because you're not accounting for the image view's `.aspectFit` content mode.

Take a look at this example...

Here is a self-portrait I drew:

[image]

It's **pixel** dimensions are `300 x 600`.

Suppose I want cross-hairs at the center of the right eye - that is located at `100, 100` (*in pixels*):

[image]

When working with tap locations and view sizes, we have to work in **points**. So, if we have a `300 x 300` image view, with `.contentMode = .aspectFit`, it will look like this:

[image]

If we tap the right eye, the tap ***in the image view*** will be at `125, 50` **points**:

[image]

and, if we try to **draw** at that point, it will be here on the original image:

[image]

Which is, obviously, not where we want it.

So, first we need to calculate the **image** rectangle, relative to the imageView's bounds.

We can do that with a func like this:

```
func aspectFitRect(aspectRatio: CGSize, insideRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    
    var fitWidth: CGFloat = insideRect.width
    var fitHeight: CGFloat = insideRect.height
    
    let maxW: CGFloat = fitWidth / aspectRatio.width
    let maxH: CGFloat = fitHeight / aspectRatio.height
    
    if( maxH < maxW ) {
        fitWidth = fitHeight / aspectRatio.height * aspectRatio.width;
    }
    else if( maxW < maxH ) {
        fitHeight = fitWidth / aspectRatio.width * aspectRatio.height;
    }
    
    let r: CGRect = .init(x: (insideRect.width - fitWidth) * 0.5, y: (insideRect.height - fitHeight) * 0.5, width: fitWidth, height: fitHeight)
    
    return r
    
}
```

and call:

```
let imageRect: CGRect = aspectFitRect(aspectRatio: img.size, insideRect: imageView.bounds)
```

with the resulting rect being: `x: 75, y: 0, w: 150, h: 300`

Or, much easier, `import AVFoundation` and then:

```
let imageRect: CGRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: img.size, insideRect: imageView.bounds)
```

Now we can subtract that rect's origin from the tapped point:

```
// assuming
tap = CGPoint(x: 125, y: 50)
tap.x -= imageRect.origin.x
tap.y -= imageRect.origin.y

// tap now equals x: 50, y: 50
```

Then we need to *scale* that point to match the scaled-size of the image:

```
let wScale: CGFloat = img.size.width / imageRect.size.width
let hScale: CGFloat = img.size.height / imageRect.size.height

tap.x *= wScale
tap.y *= hScale

// tap now equals x: 100, y: 100
```

Note that, depending on how we're drawing on (modifying) the actual bitmap image, we may also need to take into account the `img.scale` ... for example, I might have `@2x` and `@3x` images, so the actual pixel dimensions might be `300 x 600` (@2x) and `450 x 900` (@3x).

Since you say you will ***NOT*** be saving the image with the cross-hairs drawn on it, let me offer a much simpler approach that will avoid (almost) all of that.

Let's write a `UIImageView` subclass, with a `CAShapeLayer` for the cross-hairs:

```
class CrossHairsImageView: UIImageView {

    public var armLength: CGFloat = 10.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 2.0 { didSet { crossHairsLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth } }
    public var color: UIColor = .white { didSet { crossHairsLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor } }
    
    private let crossHairsLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    private var tapPoints: [CGPoint] = []
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        crossHairsLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        crossHairsLayer.fillColor = nil
        crossHairsLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        layer.addSublayer(crossHairsLayer)
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(t)
        
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        guard let img = self.image else { return }
        
        let tapPoint: CGPoint = sender.location(in: self)
        
        let imageRect: CGRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: img.size, insideRect: self.bounds)

        // Since we don't want cross-hairs on the image view --
        //  only on the area the image takes -- check that the tapped point is
        //  inside the image rect
        if imageRect.contains(tapPoint) {
            tapPoints.append(tapPoint)
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        tapPoints.forEach { pt in
            bez.move(to: .init(x: pt.x - armLength, y: pt.y))
            bez.addLine(to: .init(x: pt.x + armLength, y: pt.y))
            bez.move(to: .init(x: pt.x, y: pt.y - armLength))
            bez.addLine(to: .init(x: pt.x, y: pt.y + armLength))
        }

        crossHairsLayer.path = bez.cgPath
    }
    
    // reset() clears all cross-hairs
    public func reset() {
        tapPoints = []
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
    
}
```

Now we can tap away on the image view and get this:

[image]

and we don't have to do any other calculationa when zooming in a scroll view:

[image]

Here's an example controller, with two buttons, the custom image view, and a text view ... in a vertical stack view in a "content" view in a scroll view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let contentView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "figure300x600")
        else {
            fatalError("Could not load testImage!")
        }
        
        let imageView = CrossHairsImageView(image: img)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 5
        
        let btn1 = UIButton()
        btn1.backgroundColor = .red
        btn1.setTitle("Button 1", for: [])
        
        let btn2 = UIButton()
        btn2.backgroundColor = .blue
        btn2.setTitle("Button 2", for: [])
        
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        textView.text = "This is the text view."
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(btn1)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(btn2)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textView)
        
        [stackView, contentView, scrollView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // let's inset the scroll view by 20-points on all 4 sides
            //  so we can clearly see the scroll zoom
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // constrain content view to scroll view's Content Layout Guide
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain image view to content view
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // let's make the contentView the same size as the scroll view
            //  using the Frame Layout Guide
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            
            btn1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1),
            btn2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1),
            
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.4),
            
            // no height on the textView -- let it fill the remainder
            //  of the stackView height
            
        ])
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        // set your min/max zoom scales as desired
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
        
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return contentView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation.  I was starting to come around to the notion that the image was centered and scaleAspectFit caused it to be smaller than the image view it was contained in.  However, translating the coordinates was still confusing me.  This explanation was perfect!  I've adapted my code and it now works.  Testing on various simulators and orientations.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Trying to trace through your imageView crosshair drawing.  Are the coordinates in points or converted/translated to pixels inside image?

Comment: @rdk - the coordinates are in **points** -- because we're dealing with what is displayed on the screen. The **pixel** dimensions of the actual image are irrelevant... If at some point you want to physically modify the image, you can still do the "points to pixels" conversion.

Comment: I do need to convert to pixels as the app I'm working on is doing image analysis.  But the marking of the image via overlays is a great idea.  Trying to understand the code so I can apply it to my app.  Thank you!!

Comment: One last comment on marking via pixel (in image) vs point (via CAShapeLayer).  If I mark via point, screen rotations may make the markings inaccurate.  If I mark the image itself via pixels, the touch point remains correct even after rotation.

Comment: @rdk - if you're going to be changing the image view frame (such has on device rotation), then you will want to either track the tap-points as **percentages**, or, convert the tap-points to **pixels** and then either draw on the image or convert back to points to use a shape layer. There are benefits and drawbacks to each method... In particular, if you're ***drawing*** the cross-hairs, a `20 x 20` cross-hairs will be a very different size if the image is `300 x 200` pixels compared to `1500 x 1000` pixels.

Comment: @rdk - that's why in my earlier comments I was trying to get you to fully define and describe what your goal is. Assuming you'll be using more than one image -- will they be consistent **pixel dimensions**? Or, might one be `300` pixels wide and the next be `1200` pixels wide and the next `800` wide and `2000` tall? etc

Comment: @rdk - Did that give you enough to achieve your goal? If not, I'm happy to offer additional help...